# How to get the children from Firebase Unity at once?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have following structure:

[image]

I used this code to get scores' children 0, 100, 900, 1000

```
public void GetRanking()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Ranking").ValueChanged += DatabaseManager_ValueChanged1;
}
private void DatabaseManager_ValueChanged1(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        print(e.Snapshot.Child("Scores").GetRawJsonValue());

    }
    else
    {
        GetRanking();
    }

}
```

I expected to get only that numbers (0, 100, 900, 1000), but result was

`{"0":{"nName":"abc","uID":""},"100":{"nName":"abc","uID":""},"900":{"nName":"abc","uID":""}, "1000":{"nName":"abc","uID":""}}`

Can you give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase always loads all data under the path that you call `ValueChanged` on, so the `e.Snapshot` has all data under `Ranking`.

If you only want to print the keys of the `Scores`, you can [get the value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#getvalue) of that snapshot, which gives you a `Dictionary<String, object>`, and then print the keys of the dictionary.

Something like:

```
print(e.Snapshot.Child("Scores").GetValue(false).Keys);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I saw your comment and read docs. I tried it, but I couldn't use **GetValue()** alone. I had to use like this **GetValue(true or false)**. Also there was no **Keys** .

Answer (score -1):

This was working, but there was a problem. I changed my scores as 50, 100, 500. However, result was 100, 50, 500. Sorting was not working because they were not number, so I putted them into list and then sorted.

```
public void GetRanking()                  
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Ranking").Child("Scores").OrderByKey().ValueChanged += DatabaseManager_ValueChanged1;

    }

    private void DatabaseManager_ValueChanged1(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            
            foreach (var score in e.Snapshot.Children)
            {
                
                print("score: " + score.Key);
                                                                         
            }
            

        }

        else
        {
            GetRanking();                                                                                   
        }

    }
```